# Python New Relic Docker - python versions differ

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, newrelic

I am trying to use new relic with python and docker.  I am following this guide made by new relic https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation/install-python-agent-docker

I have a Dockerfile containing

```
FROM python:3.9.0-slim-buster

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir newrelic

ENTRYPOINT ["newrelic-admin", "run-program"]
```

and I reference that file from my normal service Dockerfile (ellipsis to simplify)

```
FROM python_newrelic:latest 
...
CMD[... "serice.main:app" ...]
```

This seems to work except for the following error. `NEWRELIC: 2020-11-24 20:07:29 (8) - New Relic could not start because the newrelic-admin script was called from a Python installation that is different from the Python installation that is currently running. To fix this problem, call the newrelic-admin script from the Python installation that is currently running (details below).`
But the python versions provided seem to match

```
newrelic-admin Python version: '3.9'
current Python version: '3.9'
```

Comment: From the page, https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/getting-started/compatibility-requirements-python-agent, the supported versions of python are  `Python (CPython/PyPy) versions supported: Versions 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8`

Comment: Thank you, I did not think to check this

Comment: Referenced page updated, https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/python-agent/getting-started/compatibility-requirements-python-agent/, the supported python versions are 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10